# WSL2 with and without Hyper-V feature, no external connection from distro, able to ping distro from host

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Im having issues getting my WSL2 distro to get any network connection working.

Previously I was running 1809 with WSL1 with no problems.

Updated to 1903 and installed the WSL2 backport KB. Enabled Virtual Machine Platform feature. Updated kernel. Set default version to 2. Converted existing distro. Updated Docker Desktop to latest versioning and enabled WSL2 as backend.

vEthernet Adapter WSL with 192.168.97.129 IP, ip addr in distro 192.168.97.130
Able to ping from host to distro but not the other way around.

Tried all proposals regarding netsh without success. https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/hdkohj/networking_not_working_on_wsl2/

Verified that I had not VPN enabled

Installed a new distro in order to rule out that the old converted did not cause the problem, unfortunately without any improvement, same situation.

Turned off Hyper-V feature and tried again.
Noticed that the vEthernet Adapter WSL now has an ip in the 172.18.61.97 range, ip addr in distro 172.18.61.98.
Ping still works the same, able to ping WSL2 distro from host but not the other way around.

Windows computer is on a local Wifi with 192.168.10.X IP.

Uninstalled Docker Desktop + disabled Virtual Machine Platform and WSL features and did a restart cycle and then installed both again, but still same scenario.

Starting a remote container from VS-Code using in docker desktop with WSL2 backend I'm able to ping from within the container to the host using host.docker.internal(resolving to 192.168.65.2). I'm also able to ping externally, 8.8.8.8 for example.

Running the sample repo for python remote containers starts a flask server on 0.0.0.0:9000,  I'm not able to reach this from chrome on the host.

Running curl from the windows cmd-line to 127.0.0.1:9000 brings up the "reading web response" but with no progress.

Terminal output from container is empty

running curl 127.0.0.1:**9001** gives:
curl : Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server.

Terminal output from container: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Sep/2020 12:22:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

**UPDATE 2020-09-14:**
Posted a question on the Docker forum: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-desktop-wsl2-and-visual-studio-code-clarifications-on-how-when-wsl2-is-involved/98660

**UPDATE 2020-09-07:**
Added a WSL2 issue on github yesterday because of the low feedback rate here. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5862

**UPDATE:**
Updated to 1909 and installed the backport KB again
Exact same situation as on 1903, no improvement.

If I attach to the docker-desktop distro, and try to ping I have zero net access. The container running inside the docker-desktop distro on the other hand works fine pinging externally.

**UPDATE: 14-01-2021**

Updating to 2004 did not change anything, pursuing the fact that Docker using WSL2 worked did pay off, found https://github.com/sakai135/wsl-vpnkit and installed, this did the trick. There is likely some firewall rule in the VPN software activated even without an active VPN connection. This solution does how ever work regardless if i have an active VPN connection or not.

**Proposals on how to do fault finding?**

Comment: Have you tried using a different WSL2 instance (different version of Ubuntu, Kali, anything other than your existing instance)?  The differences between WSL1 and WSL2 are substantial.  The fact it works in WSL1 is not really relevant.  How networking work on WSL1 is (was) completely different compared to WSL2.  I am saying this so you don't spin your wheels trying to compare what works in WSL1

Comment: @Ramhound: Agree, that was just part of the background. I did indeed install a new distro once I realized that the converted had no network access, installed a new Ubuntu but with no difference in behavior. I will add to original question to clarify.

Comment: Have you looked at the WSL2 Github repository managed by Microsoft for this issue?  Technical advice on Reddit isn't normally reliable.

Comment: I have browsed through the list of issues and yet to find anything matching the details, but tried a few of the proposals without success. What I find missing is any good advice on suitable fault finding procedures in order to be able to pinpoint the culprit, and rule out things.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to 1909 and/or 2004?  There have been times, I have had a problem, that was magically fixed by installing a feature upgrade.  If you have some sort of networking configuration problem, that exists for some strange reason, there is a chance (small) it will be fixed by installing either of those updates (for obvious reasons I would suggest 2004 in the event this is a WSL2 backport issue)

Comment: Absolutely, 1909 is the next step unless I find some other advice based in this thread or elsewhere. I'm on a corporate computer and they are not making 2004 available yet :( Was very happy when MS backported WSL2 to 1903/1909.

Comment: @Ramhound: updated to 1909, exact same issues remain.

Comment: @Kristofer did you happen to try upgrading to 2004? I'm curious.

Comment: @JeffreyLeCours: Updated to 2004 with same problems, but got passed it by running: https://github.com/sakai135/wsl-vpnkit, indicating that there is some firewall rule somewhere causing the issue.